# View argument constructed once

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, system.componentmodel

I have the following code as the constructor of a `ViewModel` class:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ItemDefViewModel(IItemDefView view)
        :base(view)
    {
        _Item = new ItemModel();
    }
```

This view model corresponds to a child window. When I run the child window once, close it and the try to run it again I get an exception telling me that I can't call `Show`, `ShowDialog` on a closed window. Does this mean that only 1 `IItemDefView` object is created? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MEF registring instances in container as singletones. To change this behavior, you need set property RequiredCreationPolicy in ImportAttribute to NonShared.
See [ImportAttribute.RequiredCreationPolicy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importattribute.requiredcreationpolicy.aspx), [Parts Lifetime](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime)